# Map old field name and new field name from mongodb document to the same c# field

Tags: mongodb-.net-driver

Does the MongoDB C# driver have the ability to map two field names from the server to a single field in the C# class?

The reason that we need this is that we've renamed a field in our code and would like to support both the old and new field name for a period of time.

This is a typical data migration scenario and it would be very helpful if we could establish a pattern for doing this via mapping without having to add special version logic to the data entity class or to the logic code.

We're currently using the official c# driver v2.3 with server v3.2.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is very much possible. What you can do is

1. Create a new property that is not saved in the bson. Use `BsonIgnore` tag thusly and populate the data from both of your property and expose that in the JSON response you are providing. Use `JsonIgnore` to make sure you provide proper ignoring directives there.
2. Go for migration techiniques in Mongodb. You can use a migration tool like [this one](https://github.com/phoenixwebgroup/DotNetMongoMigrations/pulls). As you are using the C# driver 2.3.0 I would presume you want to use that and you can use my fork [here](https://github.com/NerdCats/DotNetMongoMigrations) for C# driver 2.3.0 compatibility.

Code sample for number 1:

```
class Data
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string OldProperty { get; set; }

    public string NewProperty
    {
        get
        {
            // Return this one or the old one based on your logic 
        }
        set;
    }
}
```